# How to retrieve certain data from Access Database and display them in a combobox

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ms-access, combobox

I have tried posting this question on MSDN forums, however, i had no success.

I am trying to make a C# Windows Forms Application for a business that will manage its employees. The application uses an Access 2010 Database. The edit Employee page is what I am having trouble with. I want the Employees to be able to be selected from a combobox in the format of:

FirstName LastName, EmployeePosition

The database name is EmployeeInformation.accdb
The fields that I want from the Database are:

- FirstName
- LastName
- EmployeePosition

The name of the Combo Box is cboSelectEmp

The current code i am using to try and get this data is

```
 private void LoadDataToCbo()
    {
        string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=EmployeeInformation.accdb";
       // string query = @"SELECT FirstName from Employees";
        string query =
            @"SELECT EmpID, LastName + ', ' + FirstName + ' (' + EmployeePosition + ')' as Name FROM Employees";
        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);
        DataTable source = new DataTable();
        dAdapter.Fill(source);
        cboSelectEmp.DataSource = source;
        //cboSelectEmp.ValueMember = "FirstName";
        //cboSelectEmp.DisplayMember = "FirstName";

        cboSelectEmp.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cboSelectEmp.ValueMember = "EmpID";

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
private void LoadDataToCbo()
{
        string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=EmployeeInformation.accdb";
       // string query = @"SELECT FirstName from Employees";
        string query =
            @"SELECT EmpID, LastName & ', ' + FirstName & ' (' & EmployeePosition & ')' as Name FROM Employees";
        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connString);
        DataTable source = new DataTable();
        dAdapter.Fill(source);
        cboSelectEmp.DataSource = source;
        //cboSelectEmp.ValueMember = "FirstName";
        //cboSelectEmp.DisplayMember = "FirstName";

        cboSelectEmp.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cboSelectEmp.ValueMember = "EmpID";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't display multiple columns in combobox but try to use a query like

```
select EmpID, LastName + ', ' + FirstName + ' (' + EMployeePosition + ')' as Name from Employees
```

then set your combobox

```
cboSelectEmp.DataSource = dt; //dt is the datatable where the result of the query resides
cboSelectEmp.DisplayMember = "Name";
cboSelectEmp.ValueMember = "EmpID";
```

Comment: This code gives an error on dAdapter.Fill(source); An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: Oh Sorry for that! i'm not using Access db anymore for long and I forgot, PLEASE replace PLUS (+) sign to AMPERSAND (&) as a concatenator like this [select EmpID, LastName & ', ' & FirstName & ' (' & EMployeePosition & ')' as Name from Employees]